# How to efficiently select distinct rows on an RDD based on a subset of its columns`

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Consider a Case Class:

```
case class Prod(productId: String, date: String, qty: Int, many other attributes ..)
```

And an

```
val rdd: RDD[Prod]
```

containing many instances of that class.

The unique key is intended to be the `(productId,date)` tuple. However we do have some duplicates.

Is there any efficient means to remove the duplicates?

The operation

```
      rdd.distinct
```

would look for *entire rows* that are duplicated.

A fallback would involve joining the unique `(productId,date)` combinations back to the entire rows: I am working through exactly how to do this.  But even so it is several operations. A simpler approach (faster as well?) would be useful if it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `dropDuplicates` on `Dataset`:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Prod("foo", "2010-01-02", 1), Prod("foo", "2010-01-02", 2)
))

rdd.toDS.dropDuplicates("productId", "date")
```

but `reduceByKey` should work as well:

```
rdd.keyBy(prod => (prod.productId, prod.date)).reduceByKey((x, _) => x).values
```

Comment: I did run across this : looks like direct hit for what's needed here. trying it out now.